# Jersey, JAXB and getting an object extending an abstract class as a parameter

Tags: java, rest, service, jaxb, jersey

I want to get an object as a parameter of a POST request. I got an abstract superclass that is called `Promotion` and subclasses `Product` and `Percent`. Here's how I try to get a request:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Path("promotion/")
public Promotion createPromotion(Promotion promotion) {         
    Product p = (Product) promotion;
    System.out.println(p.getPriceAfter());      

    return promotion;
}
```

and here's how I use JAXB in classes' definitions:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="promotion")
@XmlSeeAlso({Product.class,Percent.class})
public abstract class Promotion {
    //body
}


@XmlRootElement(name="promotion")
public class Product extends Promotion {
    //body
}


@XmlRootElement(name="promotion")
public class Percent extends Promotion {
    //body
}
```

So the problem now is when I send a POST request with a body like this:

```xml
<promotion>
  <priceBefore>34.5</priceBefore>
  <marked>false</marked>
  <distance>44</distance>
</promotion>
```

and I try to cast it to Product (as in this case, fields 'marked' and 'distance' are from Promotion class and 'priceBefore' is from Product class) I get an Exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: Percent cannot be cast to Product.
```

It seems like `Percent` is chosen as a 'default' subclass. Why is that and how can I get an object that is a `Product`?

Answer (score 0):

Since your have the entire inheritance hierarchy with the same root element you need to leverage the `xsi:type` attribute to specify the appropriate subtype.

```xml
<promotion  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="product">
  <priceBefore>34.5</priceBefore>
  <marked>false</marked>
  <distance>44</distance>
</promotion>
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-xsitype.html

---

**UPDATE**

Another thing to try would be to give each subtype a different `@XmlRootElement`

```java
@XmlRootElement // defaults to "product"
public class Product extends Promotion {
    //body
}
```

And then send the following XML:

```xml
<product>
  <priceBefore>34.5</priceBefore>
  <marked>false</marked>
  <distance>44</distance>
</product>
```

Comment: What you wrote in an update is working and I tried it before but I wanted all subclasses to be called 'promotion' so I tried the first thing you posted. So I added:
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="product"
to my POST body but sadly I'm still getting the same exception. Should I add something else beside that one line?

Comment: @krajol - What do you get as a response when you do a get operation on an instance of `Product`?

Comment: Then I get for example:
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<promotion>
    <coupon>0</coupon>
    <distance>0</distance>
    <marked>true</marked>
    <priceAfter>33.0</priceAfter>
    <priceBefore>34.5</priceBefore>
</promotion>`